# scanf doesn't return when pressing enter

Tags: c, input, buffer, scanf

I spent the past hour trying to figure out why

```
char buffer[101];
scanf("%100[^\n]", buffer);
```

works as intended, reading a string until in encounters a newline, while

```
char buffer[101];
scanf("%100[^\n]\n", buffer);
```

does not return after pressing Enter.

Explicitly flushing the input buffer with CtrlD (in linux)
immediately after pressing Enter seems to fix the problem, 
forcing the scanf to return. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have missed an important detail that's well documented. According to [the scanf manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html)...

> A directive composed of one or more white-space characters shall be executed by reading input until no more valid input can be read, or up to the first byte which is not a white-space character, which remains unread.

This implies that `scanf` will indeed not return when you press enter; It'll continue waiting to see if you press enter (or space, or tab) again... and again... until it sees something that isn't white-space.

If you want to discard the `'\n'` that's left following the scanset directive, you could use `%*c` like so: `int x = scanf("%100[^\n]%*c", buffer);`...

P.S. Don't forget to check the value of `x`. It's particularly important when you use scanset directives, because an empty line will result in an uninitialised `buffer`, in this case.

Comment: Nice catch. I was not aware of this behavior for non-space whitespace characters.